# How to execute external commands with Python using Apache2 and CGI

Tags: python, apache, apache2, cgi, suexec

I have an Apache web server. I have an `html` file and a `Python` script located at `var/www/myfolder`. I am submitting a form through the `html` file which is handled by my `Python` script (when the submit button is clicked). But once handling the form, my `Python` script executes an external command. (see the following code)

**webpage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Webform</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Webform</h3>
        <form action="myscript.py" method="POST">
            <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**myscript.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python -W

import cgi, cgitb 
import sys
import os

# Get data from fields
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
name = form.getvalue('name')

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2></br></br>'
print '<p>Name: %s</p>' % (name)
print '</body>'
print '</html>'

os.system("./other_script.py") # gives me an error with permission
```

On my server I am `user007` but I know that when I click submit on the `html` file, the `Python` script is executed as `apache2` user. The problem is I don't know the password for this user (can't us sudo). Are the two ideas possible:

1) change from `apache2` to `user007` when trying to execute `other_script.py` from **myscript.py**

2) I know that you can change users using `suEXEC` but I have no idea how to use it.

Any suggestions?

I should let you know that locally both the python scripts are executing fine.

**Edit 1:**

I get this message before the error occurs: `WARNING: HOME is not set, using root: /`

Comment: This is really a general System/OS question rather than a programming question. Check out the permission on `other_script.py` and make sure the 'r' and 'x' bits are set for other or group, e.g. `chmod 755 other_script.py`.

Comment: @achampion For the sake of getting it to work, I did a `chmod 777` on all the files. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe this is not relevant anymore. But I'm having similar problems and stumpled upon this thread. If your other script is saving stuff, you either have to make sure that the apache2 user (www-data) has write permission to the folder. My workaround was to simply save stuff to `/tmp`.